# MinIO direct-csi does not see drives on multiple nodes in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minio

I'm deploying distributed MinIO on Kubernetes cluster. I created a k8s cluster of 2 nodes (physical machine): `master` has machine name `ip19` and a worker node has machine name `ip38` (added to cluster by command `kubectl join`).

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION       CONTAINER-RUNTIME
ip38      Ready    <none>                 23h    v1.22.2   192.168.1.38   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   4.15.0-156-generic   docker://19.3.9
ip19      Ready    control-plane,master   5d4h   v1.22.2   192.168.1.19   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS   5.4.0-86-generic     docker://20.10.8
```

MinIO use the MinIO [DirectCSI](https://github.com/minio/direct-csi) to automatically provision Persistent Volumes from locally attached drives to support the generated PVC. I had followed direct-csi [installation document](https://github.com/minio/direct-csi/blob/master/docs/installation.md) to install.

```
$ kubectl direct-csi install --crd
Flag --crd has been deprecated, Will be removed in version 1.5 or greater
I1013 08:08:02.437460 2161586 install.go:99] 'direct.csi.min.io' namespace created
W1013 08:08:02.469568 2161586 warnings.go:70] policy/v1beta1 PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+
I1013 08:08:02.500269 2161586 install.go:119] 'direct.csi.min.io' rbac roles created
I1013 08:08:02.531709 2161586 install.go:137] crds successfully registered
I1013 08:08:11.706289 2161586 install.go:146] 'direct.csi.min.io' conversion deployment created
I1013 08:08:14.752083 2161586 register.go:124] successfully updated conversion webhook settings in 'directcsidrives.direct.csi.min.io' CRD
I1013 08:08:14.783354 2161586 register.go:124] successfully updated conversion webhook settings in 'directcsivolumes.direct.csi.min.io' CRD
I1013 08:08:14.798965 2161586 install.go:159] 'direct.csi.min.io' csidriver created
I1013 08:08:15.833652 2161586 request.go:668] Waited for 1.030910794s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://192.168.1.19:6443/apis/flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s
I1013 08:08:16.293940 2161586 install.go:168] 'direct.csi.min.io' storageclass created
I1013 08:08:16.305892 2161586 install.go:177] 'direct.csi.min.io' service created
I1013 08:08:16.330584 2161586 install.go:186] 'direct.csi.min.io' daemonset created
I1013 08:08:22.615619 2161586 install.go:195] 'direct.csi.min.io' deployment created
```

```
$ kubectl get all --namespace direct-csi-min-io
NAME                                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS         AGE
pod/direct-csi-min-io-45lnj                         3/3     Running   21 (2m17s ago)   116m
pod/direct-csi-min-io-79b9667549-429b7              2/2     Running   0                115m
pod/direct-csi-min-io-79b9667549-spbwx              2/2     Running   0                115m
pod/direct-csi-min-io-79b9667549-xzwzg              2/2     Running   0                115m
pod/direct-csi-min-io-z8d2q                         3/3     Running   21 (2m17s ago)   116m
pod/directcsi-conversion-webhook-5ffbc9745b-4qh42   1/1     Running   0                116m
pod/directcsi-conversion-webhook-5ffbc9745b-647ht   1/1     Running   0                116m
pod/directcsi-conversion-webhook-5ffbc9745b-v95xm   1/1     Running   0                116m

NAME                                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
service/direct-csi-min-io                 ClusterIP   10.108.90.115   <none>        12345/TCP   116m
service/directcsi-conversion-webhook      ClusterIP   10.96.66.192    <none>        443/TCP     116m
service/directcsi-validation-controller   ClusterIP   10.110.11.236   <none>        443/TCP     115m

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/direct-csi-min-io   2         2         2       2            2           <none>          116m

NAME                                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/direct-csi-min-io              3/3     3            3           115m
deployment.apps/directcsi-conversion-webhook   3/3     3            3           116m

NAME                                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/direct-csi-min-io-79b9667549              3         3         3       115m
replicaset.apps/directcsi-conversion-webhook-5ffbc9745b   3         3         3       116m
```

And my problem is I only see drives in master node (machine name `ip19`) but not see drives in machine `ip38`.

```
$ kubectl direct-csi drives ls
 DRIVE      CAPACITY  ALLOCATED  FILESYSTEM  VOLUMES  NODE  ACCESS-TIER  STATUS                                                                                                                                                                              
 /dev/sda2  1.0 GiB   493 MiB    ext4        -        ip19  -            Available                                                                                                                                                                           
 /dev/sdb   1.8 TiB   1.8 TiB    -           -        ip19  -            Available                                                                                                                                                                           
 /dev/sdc   1.8 TiB   30 GiB     ext4        -        ip19  -            Available*  failed to format drive ; error while formatting: exit status 1 output: mkfs.xfs: cannot open /dev/sdc/41404a36-7eca-41ff-9d04-38f1548fc97a: No such device or address   
 /dev/sdd   1.8 TiB   1.8 TiB    -           -        ip19  -            Available                                                                                                                                                                           
 /dev/sde   1.8 TiB   1.8 TiB    -           -        ip19  -            Available                                                                                                                                                                           
 /dev/sdf   3.6 TiB   3.6 TiB    -           -        ip19  -            Available                                                                                                                                                                           
 /dev/sdg   3.6 TiB   3.6 TiB    -           -        ip19  -            Available                                                                                                                                                                           
 /dev/sdh   3.6 TiB   3.6 TiB    -           -        ip19  -            Available
```

How can I see all drives in all nodes of k8s cluster?